# How to programmatically load an .pdf image from the Images.xcassets

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried this:

```
self.relationshipImage.image = UIImage(named: "pic1")

self.relationshipImage.image = UIImage(named: "pic2", inBundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
```

Where `pic1` and `pic2` are `.pdf` files. I can select them in the storyboard, but not programmatically.

Any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on where your asset catalog is being stored, you may have to explicitly point to its enclosing bundle. You try this code:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.classForCoder)
let image = UIImage(named: "pic1", inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
```

This will look for the image in the same bundle as the class where you are requesting the image.

Comment: image is nil for me.

Comment: it doesn't work. Why is it marked as a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer to the image with this.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing.